# WPF 2d vector-graphics library

Tags: wpf, 2d, vector-graphics

I'm looking for a WPF library for 2d vector graphics.

Required features

API for:

- drawing shapes
- editing shapes
- highlighting shapes

Optional features:

- possibility to save image to a binary file and to load image from such file (format doesn't matter)
- own editor which has UI for creating and editing shapes and which can be integrated in an application (WPF control or external application)

Both free and commercial libraries are acceptable.

P.S. In the last resort WinFroms libraries are acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You might could use some of the classes from this cool geometry tool.

http://livegeometry.codeplex.com/

or this:

http://wpfholepatterns.codeplex.com/